# $\operatorname{Hom}_k(k,V)$ is a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, modules

Is it true that a vector space is just the set of maps from the underlying field to the space itself.  I.e. if $V$ is a vector space of the field $k$ then
$$
V\cong \operatorname{Hom}_k(k,V)
$$ if so then this would make an intuitive understanding of the dual space $V^*$ somewhat trivial since
$$
V^{**}\cong V\cong \operatorname{Hom}_k(k,V)\implies V^*=\operatorname{Hom}_k(V,k) 
$$
If true, an explanation of why $V\cong \operatorname{Hom}_k(k,V)$ with a simple example or two would provide a lot of clarity for me since I could easily grasp the dual vector space idea from that point.

Edit:  I actually had to read two proposed answers a couple times for the idea to sink in but I could only pick one answer.

Comment: That isomorphism is indeed valid.  I am not at all clear about what your "intuitive understanding is", per the implication you've written.  I suppose you're saying that $[\operatorname{Hom}_k(k,V)]^* \cong \operatorname{Hom}_k(V,k)$ is "obviously true" for some reason.  Is that so?

Comment: Yes, $[\operatorname{Hom}_k(k,V)]^* \cong \operatorname{Hom}_k(V,k)$ is how I arrived at the implication.

Comment: Is there an intuitive justification you have for the isomorphism $[\operatorname{Hom}_k(k,V)]^* \cong \operatorname{Hom}_k(V,k)$?  Note that this isomorphism (generally) fails to hold if $V$ is infinite dimensional.

Comment: What @Omnomnomnom says generally fails for infinite-dimensional spaces is $[\operatorname{Hom}_k(V,W)]^* \cong \operatorname{Hom}_k(W,V)$.

Comment: More generally if $R$ is any unital ring and $M$ is an $R$-module, there is a natural isomorphism between $\hom_R(R,-)$ and the identity functor. (Also, @Omnomnomnom's last comment is incorrect.)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom:  I suppose intuitive was the wrong word for me to use;  I have an understanding of the iso $[\operatorname{Hom}_k(k,V)]^* \cong \operatorname{Hom}_k(V,k)$ from trying to understand the relationship of homology with cohomology.  I had to learn a little homological algebra plus some category theory during that process.

Comment: @arctictern was it? I thought it fails whenever $V \not \cong V^*$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom $\hom(k,V)\cong V$ is true for all $V$ and $V^*=\hom(V,k)$ by definition. Therefore, $\hom(k,V)^*\cong V^*=\hom(V,k)$. You're probably thinking of the other way around: the statement $\hom(V,k)^*\cong \hom(k,V)$ is equivalent to $(V^*)^*\cong V$, which is not true if $V$ is infinite-dimensional.

Comment: @arctictern oh my, it was dumber than that. In any case, I see it, thank you for correcting me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works even for infinite-dimensional vector spaces (or for that matter for general  modules over unital rings): The map
$$ f \in \operatorname{Hom}_k(k,V) \mapsto f(1) \in V $$
is always vector space isomorphism. You don't need duals for that.

This is clearly injective and a homomorphism; to see that it is surjective, note that $v\in V$ corresponds to the map $t\in k\mapsto t\cdot v\in V$.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, we have $\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom} V \cong \Hom_k(k,V)$.  To see that this is the case, note that we have the (natural) isomorphism $\Phi: V \to \Hom_k(k,V)$ given by
$$
[\Phi(v)](t) = t \cdot v
$$
for $v \in V$ and $t \in k$.

In terms of matrices, this amounts to saying that a column-vector $v = (v_1,\dots,v_n) \in k^n$ can be naturally identified with the $n \times 1$ matrix
$$
\pmatrix{v_1\\ \vdots \\ v_n}
$$
which denotes a linear map from $k^1$ to $k^n$.

Comment: I'd appreciate feedback if I've said something inaccurate.

Comment: Makes sense to me as the OP.  I marked it up in fact.  Just wish I could mark both your answer and the other answer as correct.